# I Deployed a website through Hostinger and want to edit it

Tags: web, edit

I recently deployed a website through Hostinger and wish to edit the code I have written. I am unable to view and or edit my code through Hostinger and would like to know how. I can get into my File Manager through Hostinger and go into my website, see the links for "public html" as well as my index html and index.js but I am directed to below photo when I click on the link.

[After clicking on my index.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IT4f6.png)

Comment: Does the host provide a file editing interface?  Why edit directly in the deployed server in the first place?  Can't you just update your source code and re-deploy?  It's not clear to me what the specific problem is.

Comment: "how to open a file and edit it" is usually being assumed, when it comes to programming questions. I know this comment might not be too helpful, but that's the situation - and this question is not about an IDE either (which is useful to edit remote files). See https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking